# Short story about a group of scientists\explorers coming to terms with finding out that they are living near the heat death of the universe?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Can anybody name a short story (probably 1970s or early 1980s, definitely written prior to 1984) that revolves around a group of scientists and explorers who discover how to travel via naturally occurring worms holes?

The group are technologically around where humans were in the 1970s but with a nuclear powered version of the space shuttle, and start out optimistically exploring the universe only to discover that every world that they came to was either completely barren with no trace of water or life, or was covered with ruins that were so old that even the technology in them wasn't salvageable and they could only guess at the nature of the species that built them.

Towards the end they gain enough information to piece together that the universe was once  teeming with life and habitable worlds, and home to millions of civilizations, but that they live right at the very end of the universe, near to its inevitable heat death, and that absolutely every other form of life, right down to bacteria, outside of their home world had been gone for billions of years, making their home world the last habitable place in the entire of existence, and them the only remaining intelligent species.

Comment: I'm confused. The story is set trillions of years in the future, or in the near future? They use those wormholes to travel from  the year 1970 to the year 1,000,000,000,000,000?

Comment: It's set in the far future. A group of explorers from an alien race go out into space looking for life only to find that there isn't any. It's all gone, and has been gone for so long that it's almost impossible to tell what it was like, and there isn't going to be any more, because the rest of the universe is dead and barren. Not even microbes.